# Generic type in class declaration

Tags: java, generics, interface

I have

1) a basic interface,

2) a few classes that implement this interface,

3) and a generic class that I want to accept, as a parameter, any of the implementing classes

I have tried the following:

```
public class Foo extends Bar<? extends SomeInterface> {

    public Foo(List<? extends SomeInterface> someInterfaceList) {
        super(someInterfaceList);
    }

    ...
}
```

I receive the error `No Wildcard Expected`.  Elsewhere in my code I have statements such as `List<? extends SomeInterface>` and I receive no errors, so why am I running into problems here?  How can I fix this problem and still get the desired results?

I have tried search 'No Wildcard Expected' and 'wildcard in class declaration' to no avail.  Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 11, accepted):

It sounds like you want to declare a generic type argument that you will reference elsewhere.  Wildcards only make sense when the type is used only once, and when declaring a generic type parameter for a class this doesn't make any sense.

Try this instead:

```
public class Foo<T extends SomeInterface> extends Bar<T> {

    public Foo(List<T> someInterfaceList) {
        super(someInterfaceList);
    }

    ...
}
```

As your code was written, there was no way for the user of your class to specify the generic type argument for `Bar<>`, since `Foo` wasn't itself a generic type.

Further, if this were possible, it would have been possible for the generic argument to `Bar<>` to be different than the generic argument to `List<>` -- as long as both types implemented `SomeInterface` there would not be a compile-time issue with these definitions, but there could have been a much more confusing error message later when you incorrectly assumed that both types must be the same.

So, declare the generic type *once* as a generic argument to the `Foo` class, and then use that type (`T` in my example) elsewhere to refer to that type instead of accepting some new generic type argument that may not refer to the same type.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not exactly sure what you're looking for, so it might help if you could provide a little more detail. Perhaps you could be a little more specific about how you're planning to instantiate and use these objects?

Anyways, I think you might be looking for something like this:

```
import java.util.List;

public class Foo<T extends SomeInterface> {
  public Foo(List<T> someInterfaceList) {
    for (T item : someInterfaceList) {
      // do something with each item
    }
  }
}

class Bar<T> {}

interface SomeInterface<T> {
  T x(T y);
}
```

Or, alternatively, you could just use the following for the constructor:

```
public Foo(List someInterfaceList) {
```

but you wouldn't have an easy way of getting the type T of the items in the list.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, @cdhowie beat you to the answer though